# How to provide data from HTML form to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, azure

I am having trouble understanding how to pass my form data from my website back to my `Controller` and use that code for a more robust application. I have a form on my Index page where all it has is `radio buttons` and `checkboxes` Depending on what is selected I want to pass that data back to my Controller where the generation of a Azure SAS is happening.

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<form id="sasTokenOptions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title">SAS Token Duration</div>
                <p></p>
                <p>Please select a the duration of the SAS Token.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="radio" id="">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1" />1 hour</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="24" />24 hours</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="720" />30 days</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-title">SAS Token Access Permission</div>
                <p></p>
                <p>Please select the SAS Token's permission.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="optcheck" value="1">Read</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="optcheck" value="2">Write</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="optcheck" value="8">List</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="optcheck" value="4">Delete</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-genSas">Generate SAS Token</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input[name=optradio]').on('change', function () {
    alert($('input[name=optradio]:checked', '#sasTokenOptions').val());
})

$('input[name=optcheck]').on('change', function () {
    var result = null; 
    $('input[name=optcheck]:checked', "#sasTokenOptions").each(function () {

        switch ($('input[name=optcheck]:checked', "#sasTokenOptions").val()) {
            case( $('input[name=optcheck]:checked', "#sasTokenOptions") == 1 || "1"):
                result = "Read";
                break;
            case ($('input[name=optcheck]:checked', "#sasTokenOptions") == 2 || "2"): 
                result = "Write";
                break;
            case ($('input[name=optcheck]:checked', "#sasTokenOptions") == 8 || "8"):
                result = "List";
                break;
            case ($('input[name=optcheck]:checked', "#sasTokenOptions") == 4 || "4"):
                result = "Delete";
                break;
        }

        alert(result);
    })
});

$("#btn-genSas").click(function () {
    $(".sasToken").show();
    //generate a SAS and display it to screen
});

});
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateSas()
    {

        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=;";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("publiccontainer");

        var sasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        });

        return View();
    }
```

As you can tell I have some form with some radio buttons and check boxes in my HTML page. I just want to return that data back to my Controller where it is creating the Azure instance and create a SAS Token then return that back to the View().

Comment: In the `GenerateSas()` controller, I don't see any code where you get the form value, like `Request.Form["optradio"];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST the form data back to your controller which is generally done using a submit action on the form.  You can accomplish this in a couple of ways:

**HTML**

- On the form tag, set the "action" attribute to point to your controller method.
- still on the form tag, set the "method" attribute to "post"
- change the form's button from type=button to type=submit

**Javascript**

- in your button click method, add:

```js
$('#sasTokenOptions').submit();
```

You also need to change your controller's method to accept the parameters that your form is posting back.  There's a good example of how to do all of this in MVC 5 here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to pass the required parameters from html to controller post action.

```
<form action="" id="sasTokenOptions" method="post">
...
</form>
```

In button click handler,

```
    $("#btn-genSas").click(function () {
         document.getElementById("#sasTokenOptions").action="/YourControllerName/GenerateSas";
document.getElementById("#sasTokenOptions").submit();
        $(".sasToken").show();
        //generate a SAS and display it to screen 
    });
```

In Controller action method,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateSas(string optradio, string optcheck)
    {

        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=;";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("publiccontainer");

        var sasToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        });

        return View();
    }
```

Now you can get the passed values in controller.